# Computing the distance of an image embedding against a group of image embeddings

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, computer-vision

How to properly get the distance of an image embedding against a list/group of another image embedding?

I have a pretrained model that i am using to extract embeddings from images, and i would like to get the distance of an image against few other images i.e.

```
Embedding (1028,) against Embedding (5, 1028)
```

I am trying to do an image similarity experiment where im using the Cosine similarity metric from Tensorflow to compute the distance between two embedding, and it works well on a 1-to-1 computation i.e.

```
Embedding_1 = (1028,)
Embedding_2 = (1028,)
metrics.CosineSimilarity(Embedding_1, Embedding_2)
```

but i can't figure out how to do it on a 1-to-N distance computation.

```
Embedding_1 = (1028,)
Embedding_Group = [(1028,),(1028,),(1028,),(1028,),(1028,)]
```

Comment: How about calculating multiple 1-1 then calculate the mean?

Comment: Thanks, I did a similar approach based on your answer. I got the mean of Embedding Group then used that to get the distance against Embedding_1. It worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be done with [broadcasting](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.broadcasting.html). Iterating over images and computing distance for each individual pair is bad idea in this case since it won't be parallelized (unless you know how to do it  yourself).

```py
import tensorflow as tf

embedding = tf.constant([1., 1.]) # your shape here is (1028,) instead of (2,)
embedding_group = tf.constant([[1., 1.], [1., 2.], [0., 1.]]) # your shape here is (5, 1028) instead of (3, 2)
norm_embedding = tf.nn.l2_normalize(embedding[None, ...], axis=-1)
norm_embedding_group = tf.nn.l2_normalize(embedding_group, axis=-1)
similarity = tf.reduce_sum(norm_embedding * norm_embedding_group, axis=-1) # cosine similarity of same shape as number of samples

print(norm_embedding.numpy())
print(norm_embedding_group.numpy())
print(similarity.numpy())
# [[0.7071067 0.7071067]]
# [[0.7071067  0.7071067 ]
#  [0.44721356 0.8944271 ]
#  [0.         1.        ]]
# [0.9999998  0.94868314 0.7071067 ]
```